# Using 'passport.isAuthenticated()' to check multiple user roles in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Here's my `isAuthenticated` function:

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

And here's a route for rendering view by using PassportJs `isAuthenticated()` function.

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard');
});
```

This `isAuthenticated` function will render that view for all logged in users. Similarly I want some other view only accessible to admin users. Rather than creating a separate strategy or function in this case, can I use the same function for achieve this?

Like providing user role as parameter to `isAuthenticated` function and an additional check within function to check if the user object in request have the same role as provided in parameter? Or any other similar way to avoid writing another separate function/strategy? Also what would be the preferred & best approach? I'll appreciate if somebody can explain it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Passport stores the user info in sessions and uses these two sessions to serialize and deserialize users,

```
passport.serializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
    //Check user permission here and assign to user object.
    //user.permission = "user_permission"
    return done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```

Inside your auth function you can check the permission as,

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    if(req.user.permission === 'user_permission'){
       //route for admin
    }else{
       //rote for non-admin
    }
  }else{
    res.redirect('/');
  } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, But i think there's bit confusion. `isAuthenciated` is a single (sort of) global function which we use as middleware for all routes that needs to be accessed by authenticated users only. There's a page (say dashboard) and that would be accessible to admin user only so how can i use the same function here?

Comment: isAuthenticated checks whether the user is authenticated to access the website and then we have another check for permissions which will check wether the user is eligible to access that particular page or not.

Comment: Say, there's are two routes `profile` & `dashboard` and we wanna give all logged-in users access to `profile` route but just admin user can access `dashboard` route. how can we use that same `isauthenticated` function for both cases?